# My UserControl's DependencyProperty is not being set

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I am having a problem with a DependencyProperty.  I can't set my DependencyProperty to anything other than what I set as the default in `DependencyProperty.Register(...)`

I have a UserControl that contains a DataGrid.  The UserControl has a DependencyProperty that accepts a collection of business objects.  I want the ItemsSource of the DataGrid in the UserControl to be set via my DependencyProperty.

The DataGrid in my UserControl.xaml is:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

My UserControl.xaml.cs code is:

```
public MyGrid()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
}

public BObjectCollection Rows
{
    get { return (BObjectCollection)GetValue(RowsCustomProperty); /* never gets called */ }
    set { SetValue(RowsCustomProperty, value); /* never gets called */ }
}
public static DependencyProperty RowsCustomProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Rows", typeof(BObjectCollection), typeof(MyGrid), new PropertyMetadata(new BObjectCollection(), RowsChanged, RowsCoerce));

private static void RowsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyGrid tab = (MyGrid)d; //never gets called
}

private static object RowsCoerce(DependencyObject d, object value)
{
    MyGrid tab = (MyGrid)d;
    BObjectCollection newValue = (BObjectCollection)value;
    return newValue;
}
```

I have a MainWindow that contains one UserControl and sets the control's DependencyProperty to a BObjectCollection (which extends a BindingList).  The MainWindow.xaml code is simply:

```
<local:MyGrid Rows="{Binding Rows}" />
```

My MainWindow.xaml.cs is:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this._rows = new BObjectCollection();
    this._rows.Add(new BObject("AAA", 10));
    this._rows.Add(new BObject("BBB", 20));
    this._rows.Add(new BObject("CCC", 30));

    this.DataContext = this;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private readonly BObjectCollection _rows;
public BObjectCollection Rows { get { return this._rows; } }
```

My problem is that, although I create a BObjectCollection with three items in it in MainWindow, the BObjectCollection in my UserControl is empty.  When I set breakpoints to see what is going on, only the breakpoint in RowsCoerce trips, and `newValue` is an empty BObjectCollection, not a BObjectCollection with three items in it.  My breakpoints in the Rows getter and setter, and the RowsChanged method never trip.

I can't figure out why the UserControl never receives the BObjectCollection with three items in it (the one I create in MainWindow).  What have I done wrong here?  Did I set up my DependencyProperty incorrectly?  I have very little experience with DependencyProperties.

Sorry for the wall of code, but I don't know a simpler way to ask this question.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the sole reason but your DependencyProperty must have the property name followed by "Property". In your case the DP is exposed as Rows**Custom**Property when it should be "RowsProperty".

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning a binding to `Rows` in your `UserControl`, but then you're setting the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` to itself. Therefore, the binding will resolve to the `Rows` property of the `UserControl`, not to the `Rows` property on the `Window`.

It's generally just a bad idea to set the `DataContext` on your `UserControl`. Instead, set it within the visual tree of your `UserControl` like this:

```
<UserControl x:Name="root">
    <Grid DataContext={Binding ElementName=root}">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks!  When I removed the `this.DataContext = this` from the UserControl's constructor, it worked.  I will never completely understand DependencyProperties and Binding.

Comment: No probs. Note that if you only removed that line, then it's only working by coincidence for you. Try renaming the `Rows` property in your Window and it will break. That is, it's not even using the `Rows` property in your `UserControl` as it stands.